# What are these different Infernal Machines from the Level 12 Infernal Machine Plan?

Tags: diablo-iii

I recently found the Level 12 Infernal Machine in Reaper of Souls. What are the differences in the different machines in unlocks?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For a level 70 *Hellfire Ring* you can now choose which realm you want to farm.

It is because since patch 2.0 the maximum chance of getting an organ from ubers is only 50%(comparing to 100% at MP10 before). Also, before if you only had 2 organs and you needed 1 more you had to "gamble" and open portals hoping for a right one to open first.

Now you can choose which portal to open by crafting a corresponding machine

**EDIT**

As you asked: a [source](http://diablomandan.com/d3-infernal-machine-changes-2-0-1/)

> - Infernal Machine of Bones – Leoric and Maghda. Drops Leoric’s Regret organ.
> - Infernal Machine of War – Siegebreaker and Zoltan Kulle. Drops Idol of Terror organ.
> - Infernal Machine of Gluttony – Rakanoth and Ghom. Drops Vial of Putridness organ.
> - Infernal Machine of Evil – Diablo and random Ubers. Drops Heart of Evil organ.

Comment: oh that's pretty cool. I'm sure you are correct but some sort of source would be awesome.